# How can I retrieve data from codable structure, which might get an empty array as one of its values, instead of a dictionary?

Tags: json, swift, parsing, codable

Here is my Structure

```
    struct AFilters: Codable {
            let colors, sizes, materials,lining, price: MaterialsClass?
            //let lining, price: Lining?

       struct MaterialsClass: Codable {
                let id: [Int]
                let name: String
                let items: ItemAny
        }

        enum ItemAny: Codable {
                case anythingArray([JSONAny])
                case itemMap([String: Item])

                init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
                    let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
                    if let x = try? container.decode([JSONAny].self) {
                        self = .anythingArray(x)
                        return
                    }
                    if let x = try? container.decode([String: Item].self) {
                        self = .itemMap(x)
                        return
                    }
                    throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(Extenders.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for Extenders"))
                }

                func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
                    var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
                    switch self {
                    case .anythingArray(let x):
                        try container.encode(x)
                    case .itemMap(let x):
                        try container.encode(x)
                    }
                }
            }

        struct Item: Codable {
                let name: String
                let value: String?
                let active: Bool
            }
    }
}
```

These are types of responses which might come from the API

```
"lining": {
   "id": [6],
    "name": "Подкладка",
    "items": []
 }

"materials": {
     "id": [4],
     "name": "Материал",
     "items": {
        "143": {
           "name": "Полиэстер",
            "value": null,
            "active": false
        }
      }
 }
```

I was able to parse this type of responses into the model and then save it to the variable

```
var filter = Afilters
filter = list.apiData.aFilters
```

Now I can't get items data even when response contains dict

How can I get values from filter?

Comment: Since your variable is an enum now, every time you want to use the value, you might need to unwrap the type you need. Try `if case .itemMap(let dict) = filter.materials.items { /* use dictionary */ }`

Comment: Thank you so much!